# How to define the datetime range using elastic search(June 6th 7pm to June 7th 7pm) to fetch specific data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried the below query by defining two timestamps but it fetches the empty results. If I give something like  "from": "2021-06-06T19:00:00" and "to": "now" in the query, it fetches the results, How do I define this datetime range of  "from": "2021-06-06T19:00:00" and "to": "2021-06-07T19:00:00" using the below query?

Note: Refered this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_math_and_rounding) for range query of datetime

```
POST invoices/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "mdt": {
              "from": "2021-06-06T19:00:00",
              "to": "2021-06-07T19:00:00",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "version": true,
  "explain": false
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your mappings? There's nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas  GET /invoices/_mapping, Added mdt mapping alon since it's long mapping. I have used mdt to fetch data
 "mdt" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },

Comment: There's your problem, it's mapped as a `text`, it should be of `date` type. `{ "mdt": { "type": "date" } }`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Now I have recreated my index mdt as the date format  "mdt" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "basic_date_time"
        },   But Still now I am unable to get the result by specifcing datetime like "gte": "2021-06-06T19:00:00",
              "lte": "2021-06-07T19:00:00", If I use somthing like  "from": "now-1d",
              "to": "now" I am getting results but I want specify time 7pm  in both from and to range. Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: If you want to use a custom format - you'll need to specify it in your mapping. Although, I'd strongly advise to use ISO8601 or Unix timestamps in your indices and deal with date formats at client side.

Answer (score 0):

Most probablly you are using different format than your mapping. By default, Elasticsearch uses the date format provided in the 's mapping. This value overrides that mapping format. So I believe if you add your format to range query you should get result that you are expecting so your query should be like this:

**Query:**

```
POST invoices/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "mdt": {
              "gte": "2021-06-06T19:00:00",
              "lte": "2021-06-07T19:00:00",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1,
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "version": true,
  "explain": false
}
```

You can check different format type supported by elasticsearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).